# Responsive navigation stays hidden on window resize (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have been looking for a solution for over ten hours, today only, and have searched many more days before that. I'm asking a question here because I'll be ripping my hair out very soon if this goes on.

My problem : I have a responsive navigation which looks like a regular navbar on desktop sized screens that converts to a dropdown menu when window shrinks or device width gets too small. On the media queries front, I think I've got everything covered.

The Javascript is what is causing problems. Let me explain :

- Desktop nav shrinks when window is resized
- clicking to open/close the shrunk menu makes the list items pop out/hide without problem
- when window is resized to its original width (with menu closed) the navigation stays hidden

Here are two examples to illustrate what I mean.

[Responsive menu hidden on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816323/responsive-menu-hidden-on-window-resize)

[Responsive navigation hidden on window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663958/responsive-navigation-hidden-on-window-resize)

I know what people might suggest : just make it work with jQuery there are many working examples. While that may be true, I'm not familiar with jQuery at all and if I could, I would rather not use a whole library just for this. I'm not very experienced in JavaScript either, but I prefer the pure JS approach.

HTML

```
   <header class="header" id="return">
    <div class="floatWrapper">

        <nav class="grid70"  >

            <input type="button" onclick="toggle(navi)"/>
                <ul class="allGrids navigation grid1" id="navi">
                            <li><a data-scroll href="#profil">About</a></li>
                            <li><a data-scroll href="#competences">Skills</a></li>
                            <li><a data-scroll href="#parcours">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
       *,
    :after,
    :before{

        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }

    html, body{

        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 100%;
    }
    ul, li{

        list-style-type: none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;

    }
    a{

        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .floatWrapper{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 1120px;
        margin:0 auto;


    }
    .floatWrapper:before,
    .floatWrapper:after {
      content:"";
      display:block;
    }

    .floatWrapper:after {
      clear:both;
    }
    .allGrids{

            height: auto;
            float:left;
            margin: 1% 0%;
            display:block;
        }

    .grid1{

            width: 100%;
            margin:1% 0;

    }


.grid70{
    width: 66%;
}

    .header{
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left:0;
         width:100%;
         z-index: 100000;
         padding:0;
         height: auto;
          -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
         -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
         -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
         transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

     }
    .header input{

        display:none;
    }
    .header .floatWrapper .grid70{

        float:right;
    }
    .navigation{

        margin:0;
        padding: 0;

    }
    .navigation li{

                float:left;
                font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
                width: 24%;
                margin-left: .3%;
                padding-top:0;
                border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
            }

.navigation li:nth-child(odd) a{

    background: orange;
}

    .navigation li a{

                    display: block;
                    color: black;
    background-color: lightblue;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    word-wrap: normal;
                    padding-right: 8%;
                    height:4em;
                    line-height: 5.5em;
                    text-align : right;
                    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
                    -moz-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                    -moz-transition-duration : 1s;
                    -webkit-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                    -webkit-transition-duration : 1s;
                    -ms-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                    -ms-transition-duration : 1s;
                    -o-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                    -o-transition-duration : 1s;
                    transition-proprety: background-color height;
                    transition-duration : 1s;


                }
    .navigation li:hover a{

                        box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px black; 
                        height:6em;
                        line-height: 8.5em;
                        -moz-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                        -moz-transition-duration : 1s;
                        -webkit-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                        -webkit-transition-duration : 1s;
                        -ms-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                        -ms-transition-duration : 1s;
                        -o-transition-proprety: background-color height;
                        -o-transition-duration : 1s;
                        transition-proprety: background-color height;
                        transition-duration : 1s;

                }

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
.header{

            padding:0;
            position:fixed;
            background-color: #22313F;
            border-top:none;
    }
.header .floatWrapper{

    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index:15000;
        width: 100%;
}
.header .floatWrapper .grid70{

        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        padding:0;
        float:right;
        margin-right: 5%;
}
.header .floatWrapper .grid70 input{
        display:block;
        color:#22313F;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #6C7A89;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0;
    }
.header .floatWrapper .grid70 .navigation{

        position:absolute;
        top:70%;
        left:0%;
        display:none;
  padding-top: 15px;
    }
  .header .floatWrapper .grid70:hover .navigation {

        max-height: 1000px;
        display:block;
    }
.navigation li{

        width: 100%;
        padding:0;
        border-radius:0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

.navigation li a {

        text-align: left;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 40px;
        border-radius:0;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        padding:1.5%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
.navigation li:hover a{

                    box-shadow: none;
                    color:black;
                    height: auto;
                    line-height: 40px;

            }   
}
```

JavaScript

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
if(is_touch_device){
   //code for touch devices


   function toggle(navi) {

        var tag=document.getElementById("navi");
        tag.style.display = tag.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
// set as defaut oposite defaut active value in document 
// here defaut is set to block cause it is none in CSS
    }
}
```

I am very well aware that what is causing problems is non other than this very JS snippet. On mobile, it works like a charm.

As the hover is still enabled on .grid70 it works on Desktops browsers aswell, but only on Firefox. Chrome, IE and Opera detect the touch and make the nav unusable after a few clicks (when window is resized).

Here is a JSbin : http://jsbin.com/ziqij/1/edit?html,css,js,output

The reason hover is still working is because I thought the touchscreen detection would work ... and wanted to go with hover on desktop / onclick on mobile.

I realize now, I'd better use a click only solution and account for desktop touchscreens aswell.

Any help / insight would de greatly appreciated.

Desperately,
Phil

Comment: Have you considered using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: No, I am still learning CSS and for the time being I do everthing by myself. I know it's time consuming, but I'd like to be able to do a bunch of stuff without having to rely on frameworks and / or libraries! :)

Comment: If you only goal is to learn `CSS` then go ahead and struggle.  If at some point you will need to produce real-life deliverables, learn tools of the trade.

Comment: I am aware of that. But for now I prefer to concentrate on doing it myself and learn. And I don't mean to be rude, but I didn't ask to be lectured about how I should approach CSS.